# PowerShell ConvertTo-SecureString Syntax

Tags: powershell, syntax

I've got a problem understanding the syntax of the ConvertTo-SecureString cmdlet.
From the help: 
`ConvertTo-SecureString [-String] <String> [[-AsPlainText]] [[-Force]] [<CommonParameters>]`.
The single square bracket means: an optional parameter, right?
And the double square brackets around -AsPlainText and -Force?
Thanks for your help
Purclot Avignon

Answer (score 1):

That means that `AsPlainText` and `Force` is optional positional switch parameters. So you can call it like this:

```
ConvertTo-SecureString 'Password' -AsPlainText -Force
```

like this:

```
ConvertTo-SecureString 'Password' $true $true
```

or like this:

```
ConvertTo-SecureString ${Value from ConvertFrom-SecureString command}
```

Parameter definition for mandatory named parameter look like this:

```
-ParameterName <ParameterType>
```

If parameter is optional, that adds square brackets around it:

```
[-ParameterName <ParameterType>]
```

If parameter is positional (parameter name optional), that adds square brackets around parameter name:

```
[-ParameterName] <ParameterType>
```

If parameter is switch parameter, that removes `<ParameterType>` part:

```
-ParameterName
```

So, when you have optional positional switch parameter it would be like this (two square brackets and no `<ParameterType>` part):

```
[[-ParameterName]]
```

And it happens that mandatory positional switch parameter and optional named switch parameter both looks like:

```
[-ParameterName]
```

Comment: Hi PetSerAl,
thanks for your answer. Now I got it.
Regards
Purclot

Comment: great! Where can I find such explanation? I always try to use the PS help in first place, but this time it was hard to get the grip from it...

Comment: @Purclot You can use [`Get-Help about_Command_Syntax`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847867.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

No you got it wrong. `[-String] <String>` is not an optional parameter rather it's a required parameter. `[-AsPlainText]` and `[-Force]` are both optional parameter.

See documentation [`ConvertTo-SecureString`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849818.aspx) specifically the `Parameters` section and in that see the value of `Required?` attribute.

Comment: Hi Rahul, I was asking about the meaning of the double brackets around the parameter -AsPlainText and -Force. I didn't ask about [-String] <string> which I know is not optional. So: why double brackets and what does it mean?
Purclot